# Как cчитать, пригласительную ссылку?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как получить, пригласительную ссылку и записать в бд.

При отправке, любого сообщения, в группу телеграм, срабатывает, эта строка

```
invite_link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(message.chat.id)
```

Пользователь получает ссылку, но как, прописать, чтобы получить эту ссылку и количество, присоединившихся по ссылке? прописывал так

```
invite_link = message.chat.invite_link
```

но, когда присоединяюсь, к группе, в колонке, пишет `NULL`.

Бд

```
#База Данных
connection = sqlite3.connect("invite_link.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, user_id INTEGER, chat_id INTEGER, invite_link INTEGER, new_chat_members INTEGER)''')
connection.commit()

class SQLither:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

            
    def check_new_users(self, user_id, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT new_chat_members FROM users WHERE user_id=? and chat_id=?", (user_id,chat_id,)).fetchone()
            return result and result[0] >= 1


    def user_exists(self, user_id, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=? and chat_id=?", (user_id,chat_id,)).fetchall()
        return bool(len(result))

    def new_user(self, user_id, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET new_chat_members = new_chat_members + 1 WHERE user_id=? and chat_id=?", (user_id, chat_id))
            
    def count_users(self, invite_link):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE invite_link=?', (invite_link,)).fetchall()[0]
                    
    def user_added_user(self, user_id, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET new_chat_members = new_chat_members + 1 WHERE user_id=? and chat_id=?", (user_id,chat_id,))

            
    def add_user(self, user_id, chat_id, invite_link, new_chat_members):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' (user_id, chat_id, invite_link, new_chat_members) VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (user_id, chat_id, invite_link, new_chat_members))
                self.connection.commit()

db = SQLither("invite_link.db")
```

Хендлер:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def new_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    name = message.from_user.full_name
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    invite_link = message.chat.invite_link
    new_chat_members = len(message.new_chat_members)


    ChatMemberUpdated.invite_link = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    ChatJoinRequest.invite_link = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    ChatInviteLink.invite_link = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)
    ChatMember.status = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)

    if not db.user_exists(user_id, chat_id):
        db.add_user(user_id, chat_id, invite_link, new_chat_members)
    if db.count_users(new_chat_members):
        await bot.restrict_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id, permissions=types.ChatPermissions(can_send_messages=True, can_send_media_messages=True, can_send_other_messages=True, can_add_web_page_previews=True, can_send_polls=True, can_pin_messages=True, can_invite_users=True, can_change_info=True, until_date=None))
        db.user_added_user(user_id, chat_id)
        return
```